# CSS: Sidebar Tooltip Struggle

Tags: html, css, tooltip, css-position, sidebar

I am working on a project where I have a sidebar and when it is collapsed, a tool tip appears on hover. However, when `.sidebar-item-container`’s position is set to `relative` and `.sidebar-item-name`’s position is set to `absolute`, the tooltip does not show outside. It only works when the tooltips are absolutely positioned with relevance to the `.sidebar-container`.

I have attached the Codepen with the general layout and exact CSS from my project. Let me know if there is another solution. I am using React but would prefer to solve this with CSS only if possible. I tried playing with `z-index` and `overflow` with no luck.

My code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Dechsit-Naetsawan-Draco1876/pen/poByXaV)

```css
.sidebar-item {
  position: relative;
  color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sidebar-item-collapsed .sidebar-item .sidebar-item-name {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 125%;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-right: #3f59af 2px solid;
  border-bottom: #3f59af 2px solid;
  font-weight: 400;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the tooltip to show I added the following classes to your code:

[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/Dechsit-Naetsawan-Draco1876/pen/poByXaV)

```css
.random:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip {
    display: none;
    color: red;
    margin-left: 5px; /* moves the tooltip to the right */
    margin-top: 5px; /* moves it down */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Note you may want to play with the positioning of the tooltip but this is it displaying on hover

Comment: Sure, that makes it so the tooltip is below. The problem however is that I want them off to the side. I realized with further testing its because of overflow since if you set overflow-y as scroll and overflow-x as visible, the latter becomes automatic. Just a silly CSS scroll thing. Otherwise is overflow is visible overall it works but doesn't have the scroll I want.